# Firebase Dynamic Link Not Working for Relese Build

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Firebase Dynamic Link is working for my android app in debug mode but it is not working in relese mode. I have updated SHA256 in console.firebase.com too. I have updated signing keys too.

In short:

It is working for Debug APK
It is not working for Play Store Relese APK.

Comment: Added SHA1 to firebase console.?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add Play store SHA256 signing keys to your assetlinks.json file. You can find the Play store SHA256 sigining keys under Play Console developer account under Release > Setup > App Integrity

From Android Documentation:

If you're using Play App Signing for your app, then the certificate fingerprint produced by running keytool locally will usually not match the one on users' devices. You can verify whether you're using Play App Signing for your app in your Play Console developer account under Release > Setup > App Integrity; if you do, then you'll also find the correct Digital Asset Links JSON snippet for your app on the same page.